# CSS footer is not at the bottom (not valid position absolute or fixed)

Tags: html, css, footer

I want to divide my page in 3 sections (header, content, footer). The problem is that the footer is not at the bottom as it should be, it is at the middle of the page. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#page{
     margin: 0 auto;
           
    }
    
    html{ height:100%;
          margin:0;
      padding:0;}
    
    body{
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:#FFF;
        font-family: verdana;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    
    #header{
         top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height:2.5em;
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(168, 164, 164, 1); 
         background-color: #FAF0E6;
    }
    
    #content{ a
        
     
      width: 100%;
      height:100%; 
            text-align: center;
       
    }
    
    
    #formulario{
        width:48em;
        
        margin-top:2em ;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left:auto;
       
     
    }
    
    #footer{
        
            margin-top:2em;
            margin-bottom: 0px; 
            bottom:0em;
            
         
            font-size: 1em;
            font-family: "lucida grande";
            text-align: center;
            
            
     width: 100%;
     height:1.5em;
            background-color: #D0F5A9;   
            
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <div id="page">
     <div id="header">
     hi
    </div>
     <div id="content">
     <div id="formulario" >hi
     </div>
</div>
     <div id="footer">
    hi</div>
    
    </div>
    </body>`enter code here`
    </html>`enter code here`
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at [The CSS sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `class` instead of `id` for the best practice because `id` can only be used once but you could use `class` multiple times. You could do it like this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9t8e88w/)[Edited]

### Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrfbz32s/) too.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    font-family: verdana;
    background-color: white;
    background: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    background-color: #FAF0E6;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(168, 164, 164, 1);
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
    margin-bottom: -1.5em;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.formulario {
    width: 48em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #D0F5A9;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    font-family:"lucida grande";
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">hi</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="formulario">HI!</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">hi</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the code doent work if the page height is bigger than the computer's screen. In that case the footer woldnt be at the botton of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#page{
 margin: 0 auto;

}

html{ height:100%;
      margin:0;
  padding:0;}

body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#FFF;
    font-family: verdana;
    background-color: white;
}


#header{
     top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:2.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(168, 164, 164, 1); 
     background-color: #FAF0E6;
}

#content{ a


     width: 100%;
     height:100%; 
        text-align: center;

}


#formulario{
    width:48em;

    margin-top:2em ;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left:auto;


}

#footer{

        margin-top:2em;
        margin-bottom: 0px; 
        bottom:0em;
position:absolute;

        font-size: 1em;
        font-family: "lucida grande";
        text-align: center;


    width: 100%;
    height:1.5em;
        background-color: #D0F5A9;   

}
```

```html
<body>

 <div id="page">
 <div id="header">
 hi
</div>
 <div id="content">
 <div id="formulario" >hi
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
hi</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

You should use `position:absolute;` for your footer

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the code doent work if the page height is bigger than the computer's screen. In that case the footer woldnt be at the botton of the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things need to be noticed:

1. The `footer` DIV shouldn't is a child node of `content` DIV. Because the `footer` is sibling to the `header`.
2. After change the footer of DOM position.Both of
   `position:fixed;bottom:0;` and `position: absolute; bottom:0;`
   is fit for your situation.

[This is My JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/e6qLssxt/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I dont understand what you mean with your first paragraph. My english is poor. Please could you explain it to  me?

Comment: In a word, you can layout like this `<header></header><content></content><footer></footer>` rather than `<header></header><content><footer></footer></content>`

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: @william For this example, the result actually is same. But if your content has some css attribute such as `position:relative`, it will be work on the footer. This is a potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need add `position`attribute inside footer id and set it to `absolute`. You didn't mention the position of the footer that's why it was in the middle.

like that

```
#footer{

    margin-top:2em;
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    bottom:0em;
    position:absolute;

    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "lucida grande";
    text-align: center;


width: 100%;
height:1.5em;
    background-color: #D0F5A9;
```

}

```css
#page{
     margin: 0 auto;
           
    }
    
    html{ height:100%;
          margin:0;
      padding:0;}
    
    body{
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:#FFF;
        font-family: verdana;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    
    #header{
         top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height:2.5em;
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(168, 164, 164, 1); 
         background-color: #FAF0E6;
    }
    
    #content{ a
        
     
      width: 100%;
      height:100%; 
            text-align: center;
       
    }
    
    
    #formulario{
        width:48em;
        
        margin-top:2em ;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left:auto;
       
     
    }
    
    #footer{
        
            margin-top:2em;
            margin-bottom: 0px; 
            bottom:0em;
            
         
            font-size: 1em;
            font-family: "lucida grande";
            text-align: center;
            
            
     width: 100%;
     height:1.5em;

        position:absolute;

            background-color: #D0F5A9;   
            
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <div id="page">
     <div id="header">
     hi
    </div>
     <div id="content">
A
A
A
A
A
v
A

     <div id="formulario" >hi
     </div>
</div>
     <div id="footer">
    This is footer</div>
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```